# Convert base 10 integer to base 3, add base 3 number, and convert result back to base 10

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I need to create a Microsoft T-SQL function that takes a base-10 integer (e.g. 20201) and a second input integer, converts them both to base 3, adds them together, and then returns the result in base 10.

We are using this to calculate the number of terms in the future for a student. Our terms are represented as 20201 = spring, 20202 = summer, 20203 = fall, etc. We want to pass a starting term into the function as well as the number of terms into the future and get the result back of the future term.

Examples:

```
20183 starting term, 1 terms in the future = 20191
20183 starting term, 2 terms in the future = 20192
20183 starting term, 3 terms in the future = 20193
20201 starting term, 1 terms in the future = 20202
20201 starting term, 2 terms in the future = 20203
20201 starting term, 9 terms in the future = 20231 (20202=1,20203=2,20211=3,20212=4,20213=5,20221=6,20222=7,20223=8,20231=9)
```

I've found examples so far that can convert a number to a different base, but not to convert back to base10 with an input not in base10

I currently have the below which works fine for 20201 as a starting term, but using 20183 as the starting term produces incorrect results. The example below is modified and not yet complete from an example found elsewhere online that handles a base change up to base 36, which is why it is doing the string conversion.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AddTermsToBaseTerm] 
    (@startTerm NVARCHAR(5),
     @termsToAdd INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @base3 INT = 3 --base 3 is how we count terms (e.g., 20201,20202,202023,20211,20212,20213,20221)
     DECLARE @dividend INT = @termsToAdd
        ,@remainder INT = 0 
        ,@numberString VARCHAR(255) = CASE WHEN @termsToAdd = 0 THEN '0' ELSE '' END ;

     SET @base3 = CASE WHEN @base3 <= 36 THEN @base3 ELSE 36 END;--The max base is 36, includes the range of [0-9A-Z]

     WHILE (@dividend > 0 OR @remainder > 0)
     BEGIN
         SET @remainder = @dividend % @base3 ; --The reminder by the division number in base
         SET @dividend = @dividend / @base3 ; -- The integer part of the division, becomes the new dividend for the next loop

         IF(@dividend > 0 OR @remainder > 0)--check that not correspond the last loop when quotient and reminder is 0
             SET @numberString =  CHAR( (CASE WHEN @remainder <= 9 THEN ASCII('0') ELSE ASCII('A')-10 END) + @remainder ) + @numberString; --original
     END;

     RETURN CAST(@startTerm AS INT) + CAST(@numberString AS INT);
END
GO

SELECT CAST(dbo.AddTermsToBaseTerm('20183',2) AS INT) AS 'futureterm' --incorrect result
SELECT CAST(dbo.AddTermsToBaseTerm('20183',2) AS INT) AS 'futureterm' --incorrect result
SELECT CAST(dbo.AddTermsToBaseTerm('20201',2) AS INT) AS 'futureterm'
SELECT CAST(dbo.AddTermsToBaseTerm('20201',3) AS INT) AS 'futureterm'
SELECT CAST(dbo.AddTermsToBaseTerm('20201',4) AS INT) AS 'futureterm'
SELECT CAST(dbo.AddTermsToBaseTerm('20201',5) AS INT) AS 'futureterm'
SELECT CAST(dbo.AddTermsToBaseTerm('20201',6) AS INT) AS 'futureterm'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--??

```
declare @startterm int = 20183,
        @addterms smallint = 3;

select (@startterm/10 + (@addterms+@startterm%10-1)/3) * 10 + isnull(nullif((@addterms+@startterm%10)%3, 0), 3) as endterm;
```

Comment: ... @Andrew ...the code will NOT work as is for subtraction of terms (addterms < 0 )..you could adjust it for that if needed. The answer by GMB with a slight tweak might provide a well-rounded approach for addition&subtraction.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to work that out now with the example GMB provided, however, that example is not outputting the correct endTerm even before modifications, it seems to add an extra term. e.g. it outputs 20203 where it should output 20202 when adding 1 to 20201

Comment: The final solution ended up looking like this:
```
declare @startTerm int = 20182, @termsToAdd SMALLINT =1;

declare @totalTerms int = (@startTerm / 10) * 3 + @startTerm % 10 + @termsToAdd -1;
PRINT @totalTerms
declare @endTerm int = (@totalTerms / 3)  * 10  + (@totalTerms % 3 +1);
SELECT @endTerm
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a table valued function (tvf) that will project up to 256 trimesters into the future.  It uses a numbers table (or tally table) and the modulo of the sequence :)  To see how it works un-comment out the component columns.

```
drop function if exists dbo.fnTermsToAdd;
go
create function dbo.fnTermsToAdd(
  @startTerm            NVARCHAR(5),
  @termsToAdd           INT)
returns table with schemabinding as 
return
WITH
  H2(N) AS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM (VALUES
                     (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    )V(N)),
rn_cte as (SELECT TOP(@termsToAdd) row_number() over (order by n) N FROM H2)
select concat(cast(cast(left(@startTerm, 4) as int)+(N-1)/3 as nchar(4)), cast(N%3+1 as nchar(1))) trimester
/*
  cast(left(@startTerm, 4) as int) yr, 
  cast(right(@startTerm, 1) as int) tri, 
  (N-1)/3 tri_add, 
  N%3+1 seq_add 
*/
from rn_cte
where not ((N-1)/3=0 and N%3+1<cast(right(@startTerm, 1) as int));
go
```

Execute it like this

```
select * from dbo.fnTermsToAdd('20202', 21) order by 1;
```

Results

```
trimester
20202
20203
20211
20212
20213
20221
20222
20223
20231
20232
20233
20241
20242
20243
20251
20252
20253
20261
20262
20263
```

To get the term 9 trimesters in the future from '20201' then use the MAX function

```
select max(trimester) term from dbo.fnTermsToAdd('20201', 9);
```

Results

```
term
20223
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to convert the number to the number of terms it contains, adding the relevant number, then convert back to the original format.

Simple arithmetics function (integer division and modulo) can get this done as follows:

```
declare @startTerm int = 20201, @termsToAdd int = 9;

declare @totalTerms int = (@startTerm / 10) * 3 + @startTerm % 10 + @termsToAdd;
declare @entTerm int = (@totalTerms / 3) * 10  + @totalTerms % 3 + 1;
```

Variable `endTerm` contains the result of the computation.